# Placing XML Signature into PDF Document

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, xml-signature

I am working on a PHP project. Its about Mobile Id signing of PDF documents. Im creating SHA256 value of a pdf document and sending that data to Phone Company's services. Client(Phone user) accepting signature request from her phone, and phone company returning me a XML Signature in Base64 format, when i decode it, its become like that:

```
<SignatureValue Id="Signature-05556667788-SIG">....</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>....</Modulus>
<Exponent>.....</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data><X509Certificate>....</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

Everythings works perfect till here.

Now i have to put this signature into that PDF file. I bought [SetaPDF-Signer](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/details/#p-129) library and tried to use it with [Swisscom All-in Signing Service](https://github.com/Setasign/SetaPDF-Signer-Addon-SwisscomAIS#p-165). Because The Phone Company in my country using Swisscom's services. Everything in [Swisscom's Documents](https://www.swisscom.ch/content/dam/swisscom/de/biz/mobile-id/technische-details/pdf/mobile-id-client-reference-guide-v-2-8.pdf) mentioned (Wsdls, service logic etc.) same as my phone company.
Since I'm not so familiar to XML Signatures and PDF Signings, I need some help here.

How can i put this XML signature to PDF document ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: **A** if you want an integrated pdf signature, starting by *creating SHA256 value of a pdf document* is already wrong. You have to prepare the pdf for signing and then hash the assigned byte ranges, not the whole file. **B** whether or not you can use the data from that xml signature container, depends on what it really contains. To determine that, one needs a proper documentation, not a reduced example.

Comment: Concerning **B** the Swisscom documentation might suffice.

Comment: The mentioned add-on will handle everything for you (preparation, hash building, sending and handling the request of the Swisscom endpoint). If your phone company uses an own service they should offer you their compatible WSDL which you can pass as the third parameter to the [class constructor](https://github.com/Setasign/SetaPDF-Signer-Addon-SwisscomAIS/blob/master/src/SetaPDF/Signer/SwisscomAIS/AbstractModule.php#L76).

Comment: @mkl Can you give me your e-mail address ? I solved this problem. I can sign documents now like you said (prepare the document first ) but its gives me “The document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied” error. Maybe you want to take a look to those PDF' s when you have some free time. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: You can find an address in my stackoverflow profile.

Comment: @mertizci could you able to sign the pdf using XML signature? I have exactly the same signature format but no idea about how to use it to sign the pdf file.